# Why must I always press the hardware eject button when a CD, DVD or Blu-Ray disc fails to read correctly?

Tags: windows, freeze, compact-disc, eject

The compact disc (CD, DVD, Blu-Ray) has been around for at least two decades - and yet if my computer has a problem reading a disc it will continue spinning away until I *physically eject the disc* by pressing the hardware button on the drive.

Killing media player applications or processes doesn't stop the drive-grunting and software eject commands are ignored and usually freeze up the *My Computer* window if attempted*. I have experienced this with various discs over various machines over various versions of Windows from 95 to 7.

So my question is: **Is there a fundamental reason why I have to press the hardware eject button whenever a compact disc or disc sector turns out to be defective?**

It's not as if the applications or operating system are completely unaware of the disc read errors. Unless neither the OS or application stack are bothering to actually cap the read/seek/response delay at a [Hard-QoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service) ceiling?

<sub>* Actually almost any resource displayed at the *My Computer* level can freeze up Explorer in this fashion if you are unlucky (internal, external, network, virtual, etc). It has got somewhat better with Windows 7 though; I don't fear double-clicking *My Computer* when the corporate network drives are down anymore.</sub>

Comment: It wasn't opinion-based. The problem happens. I've seen happen to many people on many computers. Hence it was a technical knowledge-base question asking *why* does it occur. "Primarily opinion-based" is the most abused close flag in the entire stack network. But whatever; the bigger the Stack, the more arbitrary the mods.